# Windows XP crashes on startup when using Qemu

Tags: windows, qemu, bsod

I installed a Windows XP image on my USB flash drive formatted as NTFS. It's for my Raspberry Pi 3. When I tried to install it on my Raspberry Pi, the installation hanged every single time. So I installed it using VirtualBox on Windows and it worked fine. When it booted up, it worked, BUT when I booted it up on my Raspberry Pi, it crashes. Is there a fix to it?

Comment: Additionally you may want to try [**Raspberry pi StackExchange**](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: the question is unclear. How can the rasp pi runs windows XP? Do you boot the USB directly or under qemu running on rasp pi

Comment: It runs on Qemu. Since the Windows XP is a x86 operating system, you'll need to emulate it with Qemu as the Raspberry Pi is a Arm motherboard, which means you can't run Windows XP directly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently trying Both XP and Reactos in Qemu 3 on FreeBSD 12.1 on a Banana Pi M3.
I tried both on 32 and 64 bit systems. Both show a BSOD after the logo screen.

I think it has to do with bugs in Qemu's ARM->386 logic. Suggesting another OS version is information pollution. Nobody searches for that answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is because of some hardware related issue. Try windows 98 SE. It works perfectly smooth on Arm cpu using QEMU.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Suggesting that the OP switch to a completely different OS isn't an actual solution to their problem. Therefore this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: This answer could be improved (eg, *why* is it a hardware issue?) but a suggestion to use an alternative (frame-challenge) is a generally valid answer; especially when we don't know *why* OP is using Windows XP.

Comment: @bertieb I see your point, but this is closer to "switch to MacOS" than "Try another version of your OS" because of how radically *different* Windows XP is from 98. In this case I think the answerer would need to know 98 is actually a valid alternative before suggesting it because the odds are it's not an actual alternative. In any case, I believe we expect answers to offer some justification when suggesting alternatives, though I'm not sure if that's a hard and fast requirement.

Comment: ReactOS is also a very good alternative to WindowsXP. It installed very quickly and performance wise far better than any Windows OS. It is open source and free to use! Even i am using it on regular basis.

Comment: Download link is here: https://www.reactos.org/download